# ctrl+n doesn't open new tab in Sublime Text 3

Tags: tabs, sublimetext3

Well it start working for a while when I change the color theme, but then fails again.

My custom settings:

```
{
"color_scheme": "Packages/Material Theme/schemes/Material-Theme.tmTheme",
"font_size": 10,
"ignored_packages":
[
    "Theme - SoDaReloaded",
    "Vintage",
    "Web Inspector"
],
"material_theme_accent_cyan": true,
"material_theme_arrow_folders": true,
"material_theme_bright_scrollbars": true,
"material_theme_compact_panel": true,
"material_theme_compact_sidebar": true,
"material_theme_panel_separator": true,
"material_theme_small_statusbar": true,
"material_theme_small_tab": true,
"material_theme_tabs_autowidth": true,
"material_theme_tabs_separator": true,
"material_theme_tree_headings": true,
"theme": "Material-Theme.sublime-theme"
```

}

Windows 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Just removed one package that somehow overrides the key bindings.

Comment: which package??